# Get domain home / base address from url with IP and Port in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

Have inputs like

`url1='http://10.25.225.123:32782/actuator/health'`
`url2='http://10.25.225.321:12345/myappmanagement/health'` and so on.

How to get only `http://10.25.225.123:32782/` and `http://10.25.225.321:12345` for `url1` and `url2` respectively using the same command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url='http://10.25.225.123:32782/actuator/health'
awk -F'/' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS="/"} {print $1,$2,$3}' <<< "$url"
http://10.25.225.123:32782
```

or simply:

```
cut -d/ -f-3 <<< "$url"
http://10.25.225.123:32782
```

Comment: `/actuator` can also change to something else.

Comment: Hi @Gilles Quenot, Thanks for the reply. I forgot that there could be a different value than `actuator` un URL. I have updated the question. Please help on the same.